# Expressing Bessel's Function at $\nu = \pm \frac{1}{2} $ using $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I'm trying to solve this question:

> We can prove that $u$ is a solution of Bessel's Equation $z^2 u'' + zu + (z^2 -\nu^2) = 0 $ if and only if $w(z) = z^{\frac{1}{2}}u(z)$ is a solution of $$ z^2 w'' + (z^2 + \frac{1}{4} - \nu^2)w=0. $$ Using this result, express $J_{\pm \frac{1}{2}}(z)$ and $Y_{\pm \frac{1}{2}}(z)$, the Bessel function of first kind and second kind respectively, in terms of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$.

This is not an assignment question, it is a question that we had in class a few weeks ago. While catching up I've tried to do this but I haven't been able to finish the question. This is what I've tried:

**Attempt.**
If $\nu = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ then the ODE with $w$ simply becomes $$ z^2 ( w'' + w) = 0. $$ Since we are looking for a solution $\forall z$, we require $w'' + w = 0 $ which leads to a general solution
$$ w(z) = A\cos(z) + B\sin(z).$$

Now if we know that $ w(z) = z^{\frac{1}{2}} u(z)$ then the general solution to Bessel's equation for $\nu =\pm \frac{1}{2}$ $$C J_{\pm 1/2}(z) + DY_{\pm 1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}(A\cos(z) + B\sin(z)). $$

And at this point I'm stuck how to move forward. The answers provided are:

- $J_{1/2}(z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \sin(z)$
- $J_{-1/2}(z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \cos(z) $
- $Y_{1/2}(z) = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \cos(z)$
- $Y_{-1/2}(z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \sin(z) $

But I have no idea how to continue with the question from here. I've tried subbing in values for $z$ but with not much success. Can someone please show how to finish the question from here?

Comment: Well, you can write e.g. $J_{1/2}(z)=(A\cos z+B\sin z)/\sqrt{z}$ and similarly for $J_{-1/2}(z)$ and $Y_{\pm 1/2}(z)$. I assume you're defining $J$ and $Y$ as specific solutions to Bessel's differential equation satisfying certain initial conditions? If so, what are the initial conditions? Also if so, plug those initial conditions in to solve for the coefficients of $\cos z$ and $\sin z$.

Comment: @runway44 The question didn't have any initial conditions, the only extra comment it had was "You may assume that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$" which was why I was a little more confused.

Also just to confirm, how did you write $J_{1/2}(z) = ... $? Did you let $D=0$? Can we choose the those coefficients in this case?

Comment: $J_{1/2}(z)$ is a solution to the equation, and you just found that every solution is expressible as $(A\cos z+B\sin z)/\sqrt{z}$ for some $A$ and $B$, so it's a matter of finding the right $A$ and $B$ for $J_{1/2}$ (and for the other three too). I don't see any point in writing your equation with $A,B,C,D$ in it. | How does the text define $J_\alpha$ and $Y_\alpha$ then? If as power series, then you want to find the correct $A$ and $B$ so that the first few terms match.

Comment: @runway44
$J_{\nu} (z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (z/2)^{2k+\nu}}{k!\Gamma(k+1+\nu)} $ and $Y_\nu (z) = \frac{J_{\nu}\cos(\nu \pi) - J_{-\nu}(z)}{\sin(\nu \pi)} $

I wrote the equation with $A,B,C,D$ because my teacher had suggested to, but maybe I have misunderstood what he meant to say.

But I think what he was saying is "You know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} w(z) $ is a solution to the bessel equation, but you don't know if it's necessarily equal to $J_{1/2}(z)$, you just know it's equal to some solution to Bessel's eqn, which can be a linear combination of $J$, $Y$"

Comment: @runway44 I think he suggested something like equating coefficients between $J$ $Y$ and the macluarin series for $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$? Not really sure.